# why does my model bevel asymmetrically?

Tags: bevel

I have a model that is symmetrical at the corner. However, when I add a Bevel modifier, there seems to be an extra edge loop on the left side; the model is no longer symmetrical at the corner. Why?

[The link to the file](https://s27.picofile.com/file/8458307276/send_blender_stack_blend.html)

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: That area looks rather complicated, with extra edges and vertices on flat surfaces. Are you sure it’s actually as it appears with no duplicate vertices, and truly symmetrical?

Comment: Without having looked at the file, the image suggest that there may be duplicate vertices / a face with zero area. Assuming that by asymmetrical you mean the extra edge on the left side of the corner. You could check if *Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance* helps to resolve that.

Comment: Thank you, @RobertGützkow I will check it.